# Require looks for .dll files instead of my modules?

Tags: lua

So i've been trying to figure this out, im doing the following

`main.lua`:

```
package.path = io.popen("cd"):read'*all' -- to set the path the same as main.lua (for exporting)
local u  = require("utilities") -- this is the line that dosent work
```

`utilities.lua`:

```
local u = {}


function u.GetService(s)
    return require(tostring(s))
end


function u.Wait(s)
    local ntime = os.clock() + s/10
    repeat until os.clock() > ntime
end

function u.NPWait(s)    
    local ntime = os.time() + s
    repeat until os.time() > ntime
end

return u
```

The error:

> module 'utilities' not found:

- Then here goes a search that DOES look in the correct folder, however it looks for `.dll` files

Require has never been something I've been good at, Sometimes I get it to work, sometimes it breaks like this, if someone can help me understand how to fix this then thank you, as this has been annoying me every so often

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misunderstanding `package.path`.

Unlike the `PATH` variable used by windows and linux, in Lua you don't just tell it what directory to look in but also what the files should look like.

What you're doing is erasing the default search paths completely and replacing it with a broken path that won't find any files.

Generally speaking, to add a new directory to your path, you should add both `C:\path\to\your\files\?.lua`, and `C:\path\to\your\files\?\init.lua`, which are the two ways Lua loads modules by default.

You also shouldn't replace `package.path`, because you're keeping modules from being loaded elsewhere.

Your code should look somewhat like this:

```lua
local cd = io.popen("cd")
package.path = cd:read('*line') .. "\\?.lua;" .. package.path
cd:close()
```

The reason why it's still looking for DLL files is that `package.cpath` is separate, so you're not changing that.

Answer (score 0):

`require("utilities.lua")` should work.

You have to specify how to get from the required name to the file. For example by adding a path and a file extension to it.

If you want to require `c:\folder\script.lua` with `require("script")` your `package.path` must contain something like `c:\folder\?.lua` where `?` is replaced by the required name.

If you have your module in a folder with its name and let's say a init.lua for that module the path is `c:\folder\?\init.lua`

Just print the original package.path and see what's inside befor you overwrite it.

Refer to [Lua Reference Manual 6.3 Modules: package.searchpath](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-package.searchpath)

> A path is a string containing a sequence of templates separated by
>   semicolons. For each template, the function replaces each
>   interrogation mark (if any) in the template with a copy of name
>   wherein all occurrences of sep (a dot, by default) were replaced by
>   rep (the system's directory separator, by default), and then tries to
>   open the resulting file name.
>
> For instance, if the path is the string
>
> "./?.lua;./?.lc;/usr/local/?/init.lua" the search for the name foo.a will try to open the files ./foo/a.lua, ./foo/a.lc, and
>   /usr/local/foo/a/init.lua, in that order.